# How to move a ball drawn with graphics in C#

Tags: c#, forms, controls

hey guys I have a SplitContainer on a WindowsForms object on my Bounce Game project. I used the Panel child of splitContainer1 to draw a circle inside a pictureBox1 inside the second panel of the splitContainer1. Here is the method that I used

```
 private void Panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
             //use the panel's paint event to paint
            //specify smoothing properties
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);

        }
```

The product of the above code is shown below
[image]
I am trying to move the picture box down with respects to the button click but nothing happens.
Here is the button click move code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Console write the location of the picture box
            Console.WriteLine(pictureBox1.Location.X + " " + pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            /*define a new Point for the picturebox based on its current coords
              notice that X is constant as I am just trying to move the container down
              along the y axis*/
            Point point= new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X,pictureBox1.Location.Y+5);
            // notice that I have only adjusted the Y co ordinate
            //reassign the new location to the picture box
            pictureBox1.Location = point;
        }
```

**NB:**

It looks like the control position is moving so I need to clear all the elements drawn inside the picture box and redraw

Comment: You move a picturebox but paint on a panel. They are not connected. Presumably you don't need the picturebox and you should remove that. Just change the coordinates for the painted circle on the panel and Call Refresh() on the panel in your click Event so a repaint actually gets executed.

Comment: Am afraid it wil draw a bigger circle by passing the panel as the client rectangle to the `graphics.DrawEllipse method`

Comment: i should use the picturebox graphics to paint and clear

Comment: FillRectangle has an overload for x,y,width,height instead of a rectangle you could use.

Comment: Or simply create the rectangle you need in relation to the panel. You don't need a different control for that.

Comment: FYI, your code will run much faster and smoother if you simply draw the circle on the form (or a control) instead of using a PictureBox control to draw it for you.

Comment: and then how do I move the circle after drawing it on the form?

Comment: by creating a new Client Rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

I used the pictureBox paint event to draw the circle inside it and then update the location of the picturebox as a control. A delegate method solved the issue for me..

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //disable maximization of the form
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            //make sure the picture box is at the center of the form
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            pictureBox1.Paint += (o, e) =>
            {
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green,pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
            };
        }
```

and then move the control with this method

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Console write the location of the picture box
            MessageBox.Show(pictureBox1.Location.X + " " + pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            /*define a new Point for the picturebox based on its current coords
             notice that X is constant as I am just trying to move the container down
             along the y axis*/
            Point point= new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X,pictureBox1.Location.Y-5);
            // notice that I have only adjusted the Y co ordinate
            //reassign the new location to the picture box
            pictureBox1.Location = point;
            //redraw the ball inside the new location of the picture box
             
        }
```